# Jumping back into Calculus III

Tags: calculus, soft-question

At the age of 30 I am going back to school for Electrical Engineering. Because of the way higher education works, all of my previous college coursework is being transferred, which does not allow you to retake classes that were already successfully completed.  Since I took Calc I and II and did rather well, I cannot retake them.  It has been almost 10 years since I have had any formal math class, and I am nervous about jumping right into Calc III.

What are some recommended textbooks or other tools that I can use to prepare.  I have until the end of August, it is mid-April now.  I have been working with Khan Academy, but it seems to be very unorganized.  I have worked my way up, going along, from pre-algebra up through precalculus.  I would like to change gears and start working with books, focusing and PreCalc topics to start and working towards Calc II.

Any insights greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: what does Calc III cover?

Comment: Assuming the asker is going to an American university that operates on semesters (as opposed to quarters), Calc III means multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 8):

To give you a sense of what to expect in Calc III, Paul Dawkins of Lamar University has lecture notes online:  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CalcIII.aspx
He also has Calc I and Calc II notes that might help to direct your self study.

MIT OpenCourseware has a set of video lectures and course materials on Multivariable Calculus along with other Calculus courses: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/

Answer (score 3):

You might find [Paul's notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/) to be a helpful resource, which is organized and certainly has a few [practice problems](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/problems/calci/calci.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is an online course at coursera right now about multivariable calculus, you should check it out:
  https://www.coursera.org/course/m2o2c2

Comment: Hi, course creator here.  Thanks for promoting it!  
You might enjoy the Calculus 1 and 2 courses on Coursera as a refresher before this one.

Answer (score 1):

**Calculus Early Transcendentals** by **James Stewart**, I think it is one of the best books out there. Apart from Khan Academy on Youtube, you have [MIT Multivariable Calculus](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxCxlsl_YwY&list=PL4C4C8A7D06566F38)  and [UCBerkely](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw6pHhjhKmk).

Comment: Find a link for the book by James Stewart, don't know if it is legally uploaded- http://www.cengagebrain.com/content/stewart97815_0538497815_01.01_toc.pdf

Comment: Also check out- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322892/calculus-book-recommendations-for-complete-beginner

Answer (score 0):

You may find J. M. Cargal's list of [Books in the Mathematical Sciences](http://www.cargalmathbooks.com/) useful, especially the sections on calculus and multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 0):

I would watch some videos from Denis Auroux's open courseware lectures from MIT open courseware on YouTube.com just to get an idea. Also, looking at Paul's Online Notes are a great source for brush up material.