# Want to learn calculus by myself?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

I have always loved calculus from the time I first knew what it was. I want to learn and explore calculus by myself (I know stuff like differentiation, integration, limits, etc, which is very basic). I also want to learn extra stuff like multivariate calculus etc. I have Thomas' calculus ( by Maurice D. Weir) and Apostol calculus.

So all I want to know is

> how much time do I spend for calculus everyday, 
>   how do I go about the topics and are there any other books and websites which I can refer to apart from the ones mentioned above which will help me in my learning process?

Comment: Here's a list of some good [calculus books](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/322892/161538).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculus is a great subject - one in which I use, and often struggle with most days! Self learning is a great idea if you find it interesting - it will lead you to things such as differential equations which can describe a whole number of mechanical and other interesting physical systems.
As far as reference material - I always enjoyed open courseware classes from MIT or any other major institute. Often they will have exams, assessments, solutions etc. to accompany. There courses are found [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/#mathematics). With relation to time, take your time and make sure you understand the material before moving on. No amount of examples is enough!! Good luck!