# Books on calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

> As a ninth grader, I am having difficulty in understanding concepts like calculus, integration, differentiation and so on.

Can anyone please suggest a good book with a lucid and easy language for learning calculus?

Comment: I suggest you look at he already copious lists that already exist.

Comment: I used Khan Academy when I was your age to teach myself. They try to make it as intuitive as possible and cover most topics you would see in an AP Calculus class. However, if you are looking for something more proof based, then Spivak's calculus is a pretty solid, yet challenging book to learn calculus for the first time.

Comment: See [Calculus book recommendations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322892/calculus-book-recommendations-for-complete-beginner)

Comment: 3blue1brown's "Essence of Calculus" series on YouTube is worth watching.

Comment: I was a fan of Thomas when I learned calculus in high school.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a beginner I highly recommend "The Calculus Story: A Mathematical Adventure" by Acheson and "The Calculus Lifesaver" by Banner.

P.S. As you are a ninth grader, start with Acheson's book. It is beautifully motivating and interest provoking.

Answer (score 1):

[image: https://g.co/kgs/iYTkCK]

[This](https://g.co/kgs/iYTkCK) is an amazing book if you are a beginner in calculus.