best textbook for calculus?(calc 1, calc 2 and calc 3)
I need good mathematical textbooks for calc one, calc two and calc three, preferably alone but i also don't mind having a few textbooks. I was recently doing a bit of research and found "Calculus:early Trancedentals" by James Stewart-https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Early-Transcendentals-James-Stewart/dp/1285741552
the problem is I'm a broke high school student who can't buy it. So can you guys recommend some similar textbooks?
Thanks!
EDIT:I've found a free version of the book on an online website! so we are good.

for free textbooks, check out https://libretexts.org/. Also, when requesting resources, its best to state your mathematical background and your goals.

okay thank you! I'll keep that in mind.

You can also check out the free online lessons from Khan Academy.

yeah i utilize khan academy a lot for these, but that's only conceptually based, I need to gain knowledge and understanding of the topic more (such as getting a deeper understanding).

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322892/calculus-book-recommendations-for-complete-beginner and other questions which can be found by using site search with "calculus book recommendation".
